# Cannot build after adding CardView component

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have added the CardView component to my solution and produced these errors. In the lower part of the error it refers to `\Resources\values\style.xml` this file is present with the missing values inside.

I have tried:

- Removing the downloaded zips at `\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips`
- Removing all the various support files at `\AppData\Local\Xamarin`
- Cleaning
- Restarting VS
- Changing compile version from 6.0 to 5.1
- Removing components and re-adding
- Removing components and adding `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView` from NuGet.

What do I need to do?

```
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(66): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Animation.AppCompat.Dialog'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(80): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(83): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(84): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(87): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(90): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(97): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(100): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(102): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(105): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(110): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(113): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(119): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(120): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(123): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(124): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(127): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(145): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(147): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(153): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
\obj\Debug\resourcecache\5F2...97F5\res\values\values.xml(168): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: 
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarPopupTheme'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTheme'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
\Resources\values\style.xml(2): error APT0000: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless'.
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the support libraries. Re-add these to your project and ensure these resources are generated in the `Resource.designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your dependencies versions. Put all in same version. 
like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
```

After this, clean and build.

Comment: Thanks, that led me on the right path, I had created the error by changing the compile version from 6.0 to 5.1 and then updating the components to v23